# html get's rendered inside code element instead of a string

Tags: javascript, html, preview

I want to auto-generate a html-preview for my components, but my html gets rendered as a node instead of displaying a string...

this is my simplified example

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.preview')
const previewContainer = document.getElementById('previewContainer')

const pre = document.createElement('pre')
previewContainer.appendChild(pre)

btns.forEach((btn)=> {
  const code = document.createElement('code')
  pre.appendChild(code)
  code.innerHTML = btn.outerHTML
  console.log(typeof btn.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<button class="preview">label1</button>
<button class="preview">label2</button>
<div id="previewContainer"></div>
```

Have also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/destroy90210/pen/RwKrwqL?editors=1010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of innerHTML

I do not use innerText because

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and `<style>` elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.preview')
const previewContainer = document.getElementById('previewContainer')

const pre = document.createElement('pre')
previewContainer.appendChild(pre)

btns.forEach((btn)=> {
  const code = document.createElement('code')
  pre.appendChild(code)
  code.textContent = btn.outerHTML; // show the code as text
  console.log(typeof btn.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<button class="preview">label1</button>
<button class="preview">label2</button>
<div id="previewContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) instead of innerHTML

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.preview')
const previewContainer = document.getElementById('previewContainer')

const pre = document.createElement('pre')
previewContainer.appendChild(pre)

btns.forEach((btn)=> {
  const code = document.createElement('code')
  pre.appendChild(code)
  code.innerText = btn.outerHTML
  console.log(typeof btn.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<button class="preview">label1</button>
<button class="preview">label2</button>
<div id="previewContainer"></div>
```

`.innerHTML` parses the string as `HTML`. `.innerText` keeps it as a string and appends a string rather than HTML

Comment: I recommend [textContent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66802228/295783) instead of innerText

Comment: @newbie The usual course of action, when one knows the best solution, is to *actually post it as an answer*.